# How to get tox to use a common python interpreter for building sources from conda-forge and PyPI?

Tags: continuous-integration, pytest, github-actions, conda, tox

I have a `tox.ini` file I am using to run various processes including running unit tests with `pytest`. Below is the relevant portion here:

```
[tox]
minversion = 3.24
envlist = default
isolated_build = True


[testenv]
description = Invoke pytest to run automated tests
deps =
    pytest
    coverage
    pytest-cov
setenv =
    TOXINIDIR = {toxinidir}
passenv =
    HOME
    SETUPTOOLS_*
extras =
    testing
commands =
    pip install --upgrade pip
    pip install -e . -r ./docs/requirements.txt
    pytest {posargs:tests}
```

Prior to executing this, my CI workflow on Github Actions installs an Anaconda environment and installs an important dependency `DIALS`. Below is the sequence of events there:

```
    - name: Install Miniconda
      uses: conda-incubator/setup-miniconda@v2
      with:
        miniconda-version: "latest"
        channels: conda-forge, defaults
        use-only-tar-bz2: true
        auto-update-conda: true
        auto-activate-base: true

    - name: Install DIALS environment
      run: |
        conda create -c conda-forge -y --name dials dials
        conda info
        $CONDA/bin/activate dials
    - name: Build with tox
      run: |
        tox -e build
    - name: Run tests with tox + pytest
      run: |
        tox
```

However, upon running the above workflow, my tests that use `DIALS` as a dependency fail, unable to find the module: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dials'`. The packages installed with `pip` are accessible to my tests. I suspect that there are different isolated python interpreters being used, but cannot reconcile the two to work together. How do I get `tox` to run `pytest` in such a way that dependencies installed from both PyPI and Conda-forge are used?

I have tried to run `tox`, but cannot get it to recognize the conda environment. I suspect there may be an environment variable I can use somewhere to fix this, but cannot locate any documentation surrounding that.

Comment: I have never used it, but maybe https://github.com/tox-dev/tox-conda helps